# Intellij "Find usages" doesn't work across Lerna packages

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, npm, lerna

I have a typescript monorepo setup with [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). I am observing a bug (or a misconfiguration on my part) with the "find usages" feature.

I have a GitHub repo that reproduces the issue here: 
 https://github.com/mcclaskc/IntellijLernaExample

Let's say I have package A, with function `a()`, and package B, which includes A as a dependency in package.json, and uses `a()`.

In Intellij, at the declaration of `a()`, if I try to "find usages" of `a()`, no results turn up.  However, if I am inside B, click on the usage of `a()`, and I try to "go to declaration" of `a()`, it works, and navigates me to the declaration in the A package.

Since the "go to declaration" works, I know Intellij is aware of the dependency in one direction, I just need to figure out how to make it aware in the other "find usages" direction.

I have already tried messing with the Find Usages options scope, to no avail.

Comment: did you find a solution? This seems to still be an issue with Webstorm 2019.3.3

Comment: @tepez no, unfortunately.  I am still following the jetbrains issues though https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37907

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have separate IDEA modules created for your Lerna packages. JavaScript/Typescript usages are not found across IDEA modules boundaries - this is a known limitation. You can navigate to exported functions because they are imported explicitly and can be found by import paths, but searching for exported functions usages in submodules will return no results...
There is a feature request to support multi-modules apps, [WEB-37907](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37907), please feel free to vote for it. For now, I can only suggest keeping all Typescript code in a single IDEA module

Comment: Ah ok, thank you.  I'm not sure if it's possible for me to switch to a single module in the real repo, but I'll try that.  

I did upvote that feature request, so thanks for that.